# Circuit analysis, voltage in and voltage out

Tags: electrical-engineering, electrical, circuits

I want to solve $V_o$ in terms of $V_i$ from  the following circuit.

[image]

$R_1=95.7  \Omega, R_2=9.1  k\Omega, R_3=1.0  M\Omega$

So the solution is form $V_o=kV_i$ and I want the factor k.

I know that:

$R_{123}=R_1+R_{23}$

and $R_{23}= 9017.94$ so the $R_{123}=9113.64\Omega$

But how do I get the factor k?

Comment: Calculate the equivalent resistance of $R_2$ and $R_3$, then use the voltage divider to find the factor $k$, the factor k is equal to $\frac{R_e}{R_e+R_1}$ with $R_e$ I mean the equivalent resistance of those resistors in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

$R_{23} = {\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_2}+\frac{1}{R_3}}}$ Resistors in parallel
$R_{23} \approx 9.018KΩ$ Plugging in the values
$V_{out} = V_{in} \cdot {\frac {R_{23}}{R_{1} + R_{23}}}$ [Voltage division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider)
$V_{out} \approx   0.9895 \cdot V_{in}$ Plugging in the values
$k \approx 0.9895$